# How can you print an email in gmail app on iPad

Tags: applications, gmail, printing

How can you print an email using gmail app on iPad

Comment: Please check out this [link](http://bfy.tw/9SUg).  I also suggest taking a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) from our [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it's clear what the OP is asking, it's also clear that the OP didn't do the most basic amount of research on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

[It appears that you can't](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/1uB5R4dd80A) print from the app on iOS.

> Unfortunately, you can no longer print using the Google Cloud Print.

You would have to go to the site and print it from there.

[image]